# Javascript array de-structuring and Object.entries

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

It's pretty simple: `Object.entries` [is supposed to produce and `Array` of key, value pairs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). As such, I would expected this code to destructure

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "christian"
},{
  id : 2,
  name: "bongiorno"
}].map(Object.entries).forEach(([k,v]) => console.log(`${k}: ${v}`));
```

into producing:

```
id:1 name:christian
id:2 name:bongiorno
```

But it doesn't. I get, instead:

```
id,1: name,christian
id,2: name,bongiorno
```

What did I miss?

Comment: because your data is not simple Object, its Object Array.
Object Array contains Objects so you need nested loop to traverse data.

Comment: @WasifKhan There's no JSON in the question... plus there's no such thing as a 'JSON Object'

Comment: I added `.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b),[])` to flatten it. Looks better. Should I update the question ? provide an answer?

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno That sounds like an answer, which doesn't belong in the question.

Comment: I added [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026726/array-destructing-from-object-entries-in-javascript) follow up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is correct but your definition is slightly off, you're missing an array level (array of arrays).

`Object.entries` is supposed to produce an array of arrays of key, value pairs.

```js
console.log(
  Object.entries({
    id: 1,
    name: 'test'
  })
)
```

To achieve what you want, you can just update your log to account for nested arrays:

```js
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "christian"
},{
  id : 2,
  name: "bongiorno"
}]
  .map(Object.entries)
  .forEach(([k, v]) => console.log(
    `${k.join(':')} ${v.join(':')}`
  ));
```

Or maybe you meant to flatten each array?:

```js
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "christian"
},{
  id : 2,
  name: "bongiorno"
}]
  .map(Object.entries)
  .reduce((arr, curr) => arr.concat(curr), [])
  .forEach(([k,v]) => console.log(`${k}: ${v}`));
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for and I did that. But, I am even more baffled by something else. I guess I will create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to drop the `map` and `forEach` and see what you did with each of the objects:

```
let [k, v] = Object.entries({
  id: 1,
  name: "christian"
});
console.log(`${k}: ${v}`);

let [k, v] = Object.entries({
  id : 2,
  name: "bongiorno"
});
console.log(`${k}: ${v}`);
```

Now if we expand the `Object.entries` call, this becomes

```
let [k, v] = [
  ["id", 1],
  ["name", "christian"]
];
console.log(`${k}: ${v}`);

let [k, v] = [
  ["id", 2],
  ["name", "bongiorno"]
];
console.log(`${k}: ${v}`);
```

which quite accurately reflects what you're seeing - `k` and `v` are getting assigned arrays.

You will need to nest two loops:

```
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "christian"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "bongiorno"
}];
for (const obj of arr)
    for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj))
        console.log(k+": "+v);
```

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno You would need some kind of `flatMap` for that, which doesn't exist in JS. But if you replace the `forEach` by a simple `for of` loop, that's an easy problem

Comment: instead of the `for` loop I just `.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b),[])` to flatten it