# Array destructing from Object.entries in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Here is the code in question:

```js
const posts = [{
  data: {
    id: 1,
    date: "2019-02-03",
    ev_filter_1: ["art", "foodie"],
    ev_filter_2: ["value1", "value2"],
    ev_filter_3: ["value1", "value2"],
    ev_filter_4: ["all", "12+"]
  }
},
  {
    data: {
      id: 2,
      date: "",
      ev_filter_1: ["arti", "foodie"],
      ev_filter_2: ["value1", "value2"],
      ev_filter_3: ["value1", "value2"],
      ev_filter_4: ["all", "19+"]
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 3,
      date: "2019-02-03",
      ev_filter_1: ["art", "foodie"],
      ev_filter_2: ["value1", "value75"],
      ev_filter_3: ["value1", "value2"],
      ev_filter_4: ["all", "12+"]
    }
  }
];

function sift2(arrObjLit, pattern, ...values) {
  const toMatch = new Set(values)
  const result = arrObjLit.map(o => o.data)
  .filter(o =>
      Object.entries(o)
      .filter(([k, v]) => {
        console.log(`${k}: ${v}`)
        return true
      })
      .filter(([k, v]) => k.startsWith(pattern))
      .filter(([k, v]) => Array.isArray(v))
      .filter(([k, v]) => toMatch.has(v))
          .length > 0
  )
  return result;
}

console.log(...sift2(posts, "ev_", "value75", "12+"));
```

Which is baffling me. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026162/javascript-array-de-structuring-and-object-entries?noredirect=1#comment77026918_45026162)
I would expect the array destructing in `filter` to be wrong. And yet, it's not. It's exactly what I am looking for. Why would the destructing be flat in the `filter` method? Am I observing things wrong?

```
.filter(o =>
      Object.entries(o)
      .filter(([k, v]) => k.startsWith(pattern))
```

Comment: What do you mean by  "the destructuring be flat"?

Comment: `toMatch.has(v)` doesn't work when `toMatch` is a set of strings and `v` is an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are now properly nesting the iterations, calling the second `filter` directly on the output of `entries`. Notice that you are using

```
.filter(o => Object.entries(o).filter(…).… )
```

instead of

```
.map(Object.entries).filter(o => o.… )
```

---

That said, I'd rewrite your function to

```
function sift2(arrObjLit, pattern, ...values) {
  const toMatch = new Set(values)
  return arrObjLit.filter(o =>
    Object.entries(o.data)
    .some(([k, v]) => {
      console.log(`${k}: ${v}`);
      return k.startsWith(pattern)
          && Array.isArray(v)
          && v.some(x => toMatch.has(x));
    })
  );
}
```